# Amount of Instances I can create on AWS free tier

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I just got a AWS free tier account and have been playing around a bit. Created a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 based instance but now I want to delete it and create a new one. Is there a limit to the number of free instances that we can create and run?

Didn't find any help on aws forums.

Answer (score 4):

AWS is billed on an hour-by-hour basis.  You get 750 hours of running micro instances per month on the free tier.

You can use this up by creating 31 instances and running them for 24 hours, or by creating one instance and running it for 744 hours (31 days).

Note that creating an instance and deleting it 2 minutes later still bills you for the entire hour.

Comment: I would like to ask another question. Is there a way to view how many days/months I have left on my free tier?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> Is there a way to view how many days/months I have left on my free tier?

1. Go to your billing page https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing
2. Go to Bills
3. Expand the details for Elastic Compute Cloud
4. In the column Usage, you can see how many hours you have already used.